# How to use returned data from a fetch request, in a follow up request

Tags: javascript, parameters, fetch-api, openweathermap

I am trying to display the weather for the city that a user will search by name. I am using the first API to be allow the user to search by city name. That will return a data object with the lat and lon that I will then use to run a second fetch request to get the weather forecast for the city searched by lat and lon. this is my current code I have worked up.

```
var citySearch = function() {

  inputFormEl = document.getElementById("city").value;
  const apiCall = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&q=` + inputFormEl + apiKey;

  fetch(apiCall)
    .then(function(response) {
      response.json()
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);

          var lat = data.coord.lat;
          var lon = data.coord.lon;
          getCity(data)

        })
    }).then(function() {
      var secCall = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${Lat}&lon=${Lon}&appid=087ab696412a7356255185b8f55d9574`;
      fetch(secCall)
      console.log(secCall);
    })
}
```

Comment: What is `getCity`? Why is this needed when the user has already input the city?

Comment: The second call should be inside the callback function with `var lat` and `var lon`. And the variables should be lowercase in the template literal.

Answer (score 0):

Inside each `then` callback you should *return* the information you want to pass on -- which can be a promise, or just a value -- so to avoid the nesting that is typical for "callback hell".

And once you have the latitude and longitude, just immediately use that for doing your next `fetch`.

So it becomes this -- I removed your appid:

```
fetch(apiCall)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    getCity(data);
    let {lat, lon} = data.coord;
    // Just continue...
    var secCall = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${Lat}&lon=${Lon}&appid=....`;
    console.log(secCall);
    return fetch(secCall);
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.current.weather[0].description);
});
```

All this is easier with `async/await` syntax:

```
(async function() {
    let response = await fetch(apiCall);
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    getCity(data);
    let {lat, lon} = data.coord;
    var secCall = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${Lat}&lon=${Lon}&appid=....`;
    console.log(secCall);
    let response2 = await fetch(secCall);
    let data2 = await response2.json();
    console.log(data2.current.weather[0].description);
})();
```